# Optionally pass data to child element via directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have a popup dialog box that I wish to display one of two slightly different views, dependant on whether I have data present or not.

Is there a way in which I can **optionally** pass in *said* data within the directives?

ie. I would like to use something like

```
<my-comp *ngIf="ifPopup" [data]="myData" [isNew]="isNew"></my-comp>
```

where the `[data]` may not always be present, ie. It may either be `undefined` or have actual data present.

I just want to avoid having to basically duplicate my component.

**Update after confusion around my question**
Basically I am adding a new record to my DB (imagine adding a new customer etc). My component will either be used to edit a record or create a new record. If I am editing a record, myData will be filled with this record. If I am creating a new record, myData will be undefined..

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use

```
<my-comp *ngIf="ifPopup && myData" [data]="myData"></my-comp>
```

in this way, If the `myData` is not present, your popup wont display

Comment: I may not have been so clear in my question, I have now updated. Basically I am adding a new record to my DB (imagine adding a new customer etc). My component will either be used to **edit** a record or **create** a new record. If I am editing a record, `myData` will be filled with this record. If I am creating a new record, `myData` will be undefined...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use `<ng-container>` and wrap your component inside and and use ngIf for your data!